# Confusion about what the pronoun refers to

Tags: pronouns

What does "it" refer to in the following sentence?

> Humans instinctively seek structures that will shelter and enhance
> their way of life.  **It** is the work of architects to create
> buildings that are not simply constructions but also offer inspiration
> and delight.

Comment: "the work of architects"; it could be rephrased "The work of architects is to create buildings that are not simply constructions but also offer inspiration and delight." Hopefully someone can explain the grammatical terminology.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who coined the term “dummy it”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287705/who-coined-the-term-dummy-it) There are many other precedents; search 'dummy it', 'it-cleft' etc.

Answer (score 2):

"It" in that context is a [preparatory subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preparatory_subject), so it refers to "to create buildings that are not simply constructions but also offer inspiration and delight." Were you to rephrase that sentence without the preparatory subject "it," you'd write:

> "To create buildings that are not simply constructions but also offer
> inspiration and delight is the work of architects."

Rephrasing your sentence as shown above eliminates the preparatory subject and replaces the pronoun "it" with the actual subject, illustrating that "it" in your sentence must refer to "to create buildings that are not simply constructions but also offer inspiration and delight" as its antecedent, "antecedent" being a misnomer in situations like this since what the pronoun refers to comes *post* rather than *ante*.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *"It is the work of architects to create buildings*
> *that are not simply constructions but also offer inspiration and*
> *delight*.

[1] is an **extraposition** construction, where the dummy pronoun "it" is subject and the infinitival clause "to create buildings that are not simply constructions but also offer inspiration and delight" is an extraposed subject corresponding to the subject of the basic version, [2], where the infinitival clause is subject.

> [2] *To create buildings that are not simply constructions but also offer*
> *inspiration and delight is the work of architects.*

Note than in extraposition the "it" is a dummy element  serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position; the extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of "it" but serves simply as a semantic argument of the VP.

Comment: Whoever down-voted my answer should speak up and say why.

Comment: Drive-by down-voters, one of the curses of this site. Let me correct that for you. +1